# What am I, seen everyday?

Tags: riddle

I have a mouth, but I don't eat with it

My body doesn't support me, yet I eat with that

I have a comfy bed, yet I never sleep with it

whether it is night or day

I love to run, but can't slow down to a jog

 yet I can a raging bull

I can be shorter than a dwarf

 or taller than a skyscraper

You better watch out

 the hope for survival

 just turned to your worst nightmare

What am I, seen everyday?

Comment: @PythonMaster could you respond to my question and tell me if i'm right?

Comment: This is hard! Won't stop trying though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't fit all of the verses, but one that fits some is

> river

```
I have a mouth, but I don't eat with it
...
I have a comfy bed, yet I never sleep with it
whether it is night or day

I love to run, but can't slow down to a jog
```

> A river has a mouth and a bed, and it runs but can't slow down.

```
I can be shorter than a dwarf
or taller than a skyscraper
```

> A river can be short, or it can have a waterfall that makes it taller than a skyscraper

The parts I can't fit yet are:

```
My body doesn't support me, yet I eat with that
...
yet I can a raging bull
...
You better watch out
the hope for survival
just turned to your worst nightmare
```

I don't even know what the line about the bull means. Is a word missing?

Comment: This was my initial interpretation as well. The way I read it, the line about the bull means "[I] can't slow down to a jog, yet I can [slow] a raging bull [down to a jog]", i.e. a raging bull can't run upstream very fast.

Comment: `My body doesn't support me, yet I eat with that` could be because other rivers flow into the body of the river.

Comment: "yet I can a raging bull" might mean that river can be destructive in floods.

Comment: however this answer doesn't explain the title. :-\

Comment: Does it make sense if the answer is `water`?

Comment: Also matches up with my initial thought. A river is a body of water that "eats" at the riverbed/sides through erosion. A river when flooded can also be a "raging" river. Not quite a full match, though.

Comment: There is a fairly well-known (and old) riddle that goes: "I always run, but never walk. I have a bed, but I don't sleep. I have a mouth, but I don't eat." to which the answer is ***river*** so I think this is it. Note the survival/nightmare refers to flood plains ([wikipedia articles sums up why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floodplain#Ecology))

Comment: Right answer, wrong reasoning

Answer (score 4):

You're

> A human shadow, or just a shadow?

This would explain the title as these are seen everyday

I have a mouth but, I don't eat with it

> As long as the object has a mouth then so does the shadow, but a shadow can't eat

My body doesn't support me, but I eat with that

> Not sure about the second bit, but a shadows body doesn't support itself,  maybe a shadow eats the light?

I have a comfy bed but never sleep in it
whether it is night or day

> A human has a bed but their shadow can't sleep in it

I love to run, but can't slow down to a jog,
but I can a raging bull

> Don't know about running, but a raging bull has a shadow?

I can be shorter than a dwarf

> e.g. a fly's shadow

Or taller than a skyscraper

> e.g. Mount Everest's shadow

You better watch out 
the hope for survival 
just turned to your worst nightmare

> Not sure, but most nightmares consist of shadows and darkness

Comment: @PythonMaster am I right?

Comment: You are still inccorrect